# pandas adding new column to existing dataframe with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a pandas data frame like so.

| fruit | year | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 2018 | 4 |
| apple | 2019 | 3 |
| apple | 2020 | 5 |
| plum | 2019 | 3 |
| plum | 2020 | 2 |

and I want to add column [last_year_price]

please help......

Comment: How looks expected ouput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you can use `groupby` and `shift`:

```
df['last_year_price'] = df.groupby('fruit').shift(1).price
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shift function:

```
df['last_year_price'] = df.sort_values(by=['year'], ascending=True).groupby(['fruit'])['price'].shift(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for rows with maximal years and join to oriinal DataFrame:

```
df = df.merge(df.loc[df.groupby('fruit')['year'].idxmax(), ['fruit','price']].rename(columns={'price':'last_year_price'}), on='fruit', how='left')
print (df)
   fruit  year  price  last_year_price
0  apple  2018      4                5
1  apple  2019      3                5
2  apple  2020      5                5
3   plum  2019      3                2
4   plum  2020      2                2
```